# Service function not found in angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I added a service to my angular controller, but it says every time there is no function. I really dont know why and hope there is someone who can help me.
Here is my userCtrl.js http://hastebin.com/imufehimaw.js

Comment: Post the code in question itself. Questions should be standalone without having to go off site to see the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't injected the service in controller

Change

```
controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

To

```
controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http, ergastAPIservice) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should inject your service as a dependency to your controller as shown below before using it

```
controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http, ergastAPIservice) {
    //your code
});
```

better way of using it if you are considering minimizing in future

```
controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ergastAPIservice', function($scope, $http, ergastAPIservice) {
    //your code
}]);
```